# Store latin characters in php array, then output it correctly to browser, then PDF

Tags: php, pdf, utf-8, latin1, snappy

I have a php array storing french sentences (latin) with translation preparation like:

```
myarray = array(
          "description" => "more infos",
          "rule" => "1",
          "out" => __("Merci de l’imprimer, à demain, c'est l'été"));
```

The __( is here for future translation purposes. Base language is french.

If i output my text into a PDF using Snappy, i get strange utf8 encoded characters like Ã©

I then added

```
utf8_decode()
```

to my text before outputting, and it gets much better. But some characters still stay unreadable like

```
'
```

converted to

```
?
```

Could you help me understanding how to store my ready for translation text and how to output it correctly ? Do i have to encode it before storing in my array ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page. It has the answer to your question! If not then Im sure you'll be able piece the information together and do it yourself!

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-decode.php

This bit of code might be worth trying. I haven't actually tried it but that php website should get you on the right path.

```
$array = array_map("utf8_decode", $myarray);
```

#### Updated code (Ignore the above)

I've tested this bit of code and there are no funny characters outputting :) I've encoded it and then decoded it. You never actually encoded your array so that's why it was printing out odd characters

```
$myarray = array(
          "description" => "more infos",
          "rule" => "1",
          "out" => "Merci de l’imprimer, à demain, c'est l'été");


$utfEncoded = array_map("utf8_encode", $myarray );




$array = array_map("utf8_decode", $utfEncoded);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Thank you but i already used the function you mentioned. Should i store it utf8 encoded as well ?

Comment: @Max - I've updated my answer. I've tested the code and there are no weird chars being outputted